# Meaning of the expression $P(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) \propto 1$?

Tags: probability, joint-distribution

I am reading this statistics books and it keeps on repeating same expression over and over again $P(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) \propto 1$

What does the above expression mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the density is proportional to a constant, then it has the same value at each point in the domain being considered (not stated in your question).

That is, the density is uniform over whatever subpace $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ is defined to have support on.

Presumably this is for a Bayesian problem in which case a either a proper prior or an improper prior* is being defined.

* (it's quite possible that the intent is to define an improper, flat prior over say the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is a common thing in Bayesian statistics)

More context might allow more specific answers but I think this covers all the likely use-cases.

Comment: The paper doesnt say anything about subspace on which $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ are defined does it mean $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) \in [-\infty,+\infty]\times [-\infty,+\infty]\times [-\infty,+\infty]$?

Comment: It *might*... but it might otherwise be obvious that it's something else, and so they didn't feel the need to specify.

Answer (score 2):

That they follow an uniform distribution (proportional to a constant, with the adequate normalization)